# Change Language and Programmes in the installer

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, i18n

How could I change the default [language](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-KdHNUruiRXg/V4aE5kaXQ3I/AAAAAAAAMdE/bcZIiN0-Bmg3pTUDkPLGD7Ln9_5jNocbwCLcB/s1600/install1.png) that comes in the installer?
Exemple: change from english to portuguese br.

I would also like to change those [programs](http://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Preparing-to-Install-Linux-Mint-18.png) that optionally put me to install (i.e., change these programs, adding others).